# iOS 11 issue with PKHUD or blur - crashes app

Tags: ios, ios11

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '> has been added as a subview to >.
>   **Do not add subviews directly to the visual effect view itself, instead add them to the -contentView.'**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue with HTProgesssHUD. And solved the issue by change line

```
self.hudView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark]];
```

to

```
self.hudView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark]].contentView;
```

Answer (score 3):

Browsing some tickets (open or closed) on your library's repository may help sometimes.

Here's an issue that is similar to yours:

https://github.com/pkluz/PKHUD/issues/196

There are two solutions for this based on the ticket:

1. Unfortunately it seems to be an issue related to iOS 11 and not Swift. So use the Swift 4 branch with Xcode 9
2. Make sure you're not using an old branch of the PKHUD because the issue was fixed already here: https://github.com/pkluz/PKHUD/pull/169

Answer (score 0):

Update your pod to the latest version.

```
pod 'PKHUD', '~> 5.0'
```